# Expanding a list of items.

Tags: combinatorics

Thanks for the help!

I have six items, $A, D, E, M, P, W$. I know that a list of every combination of the six items, without duplicating the items, would have $63$ combinations. How do I get the list of those combinations?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of all 6 number sequences of 1's and zeroes. The ones in each sequence then correspond to the elements you choose in that combination. This can be done fairly structural:
$$
100000 \\
010000 \\
\vdots \\
000001 \\
110000 \\
101000 \\
100100 \\
$$
etc.